# how to pass an array to dompdf with php?

Tags: php, dompdf

I used to work with one-value variable and pass it to my dompdf using controller(php):

```
  function dompdf(){
       $name= "name";
       $html = $this->load->view('contracts/equipment_pdf', $data, true);
       $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
       $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
       $this->dompdf->render();
       $this->dompdf->stream("test.pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
   }
```

and in my viw I did :  `<?php echo $name; ?>`

but now I want to pass data in array format (for ex product that has an id,name and price) and how to show it in my view

Comment: `$product = [$name,$id,$price];` this way you can pass

Comment: you in laravel right ?

Comment: @Mohamed and how to call it in my view ??

Comment: @yahya `https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable` official doc is this. if you need more clarification write down a comment again